# JavaScript function syntax in Next.js / JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am about to make a function where you can choose sizes. It works when you use just JavaScript with HTML. Is my syntax from the JavaScript function correct? Because I am getting an Error from Next.js.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iTlg.png) is the error message I am getting from Next.js.

```
import React from "react";
const ChangeSize = () => {
  const sizes = document.querySelectorAll(".size");
  function changeSize() {
    sizes.forEach((size) => size.classList.remove("active"));
    this.classList.add("active");
  }

  sizes.forEach((size) => size.addEventListener("click", changeSize));

  return (
    <div className='size-container'>
      <h3 className='title'>size</h3>
      <div className='sizes'>
        <span className='size'>7</span>
        <span className='size'>8</span>
        <span className='size active'>9</span>
        <span className='size'>10</span>
        <span className='size'>11</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChangeSize;
```

Comment: hey Morten you're working with functional react component, so 'this' keyword possibly not gonna work.You can remove class as same as adding.

Comment: Should it be `size.classList.add(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally you wouldn't use the JavaScript DOM API to accomplish this type of task in React. The function and JSX would resemble something like this in a React Function component:

```
const SizeSwitcher = () => { 
  const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = React.useState(9); // 9 was default in example

  return (
    <div className='size-container'>
      <h3 className='title'>size</h3>
      <div className='sizes'>
        <span onClick={() => setActiveLink(7)} className={`size ${activeLink === 7 ? 'active' : ''}`}>7</span>
        <span onClick={() => setActiveLink(8)} className={`size ${activeLink === 8 ? 'active' : ''}`}>8</span>
        <span onClick={() => setActiveLink(9)} className={`size ${activeLink === 9 ? 'active' : ''}`}>9</span>
        <span onClick={() => setActiveLink(10)} className={`size ${activeLink === 10 ? 'active' : ''}`}>10</span>
        <span onClick={() => setActiveLink(11)} className={`size ${activeLink === 11 ? 'active' : ''}`}>11</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SizeSwitcher;
```

You can state up some state and then use that piece of state to determine if the active class should be present. Next steps could be figuring out how to reduce the code duplication in the example. Hope this helps!

Edit - Oh yeah if you are using Next.js you can leave out the React import at the top. That is handled by Next automatically.

Comment: I would even add a loop because `span` repetition is nasty here